# How to use Multi-Intents in RASA?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

config.yml

```
language: en 
 pipeline:
   - name: SpacyNLP
     model: en_core_web_md
     case_sensitive: False 
   - name: SpacyTokenizer
     intent_tokenization_flag: True
     intent_split_symbol: "+"
 
   - name: SpacyFeaturizer

stories.yml

 - story: greet goodbye story
   steps:
   - intent: greet+goodbye
   - action: utter_thankyou
```

intent files

```
intent: greet 
examples: |

hey
hello
hi
hello there


intent: goodbye
examples: |
good afternoon
cu
good by


  intent: greet+goodbye
   examples: |
     - Hi. Goodbye
     - Hello and Good Bye
     - Good morning and Good Bye
```

I have also correct configurations in domain.yml. I have many examples for each intent.

But it doesn’t correctly predict greet+goodbye

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there! it seems that the syntax of your files is wrong (or you pasted an excerpt). Would you mind sharing the full files to make sure you have the correct syntax? The few things that I note here: missing `stories:` key in the `stories.yml` file, missing dashes (`-`) for examples of intents "greet" and "goodbye".

Additionally if you could post your question with these complete files on our forum (https://forum.rasa.com/), we'd be able to better support you!

Comment: Hi @mvdb yes.. that is just a paste error. there is no syntax error in files.